# Regular Expression to enter Amount in Android

Tags: android, regex

I am trying to write the Regular Expression in Android for entering the Amount. The amount need to have Integer part restricted to 10 digits maximum and Decimal part restricted to 2 digits maximum.

This is the regular expression which I used:

```
mPattern=Pattern.compile("[0-9]{0,10}(\.[0-9]{0,2})?)||(\.)?");
```

And everything works, but when I enter Integer part, it takes the decimal digit into the integer part and so it is not able to take .(dot) and the decimal part.

Suppose if I enter 12 Integer part, then it does not take the decimal part.
Any suggestion?

Comment: `^\\d{1,10}(?:\\.\\d{1,2})?$`

Comment: I am afraid you need to clarify. In order to check if there are no more than 10 digits in the integer and 2 in the decimal part, you need to use anchors and the expression could look like `^[0-9]{0,10}+(\\.[0-9]{1,2})?$`.

Comment: I mean that the amount should take maximum 10 digits in the integer part and 2 digits in the decimal part. eg. 20022002222.01

Comment: What do you mean by "should take"? Capture? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eP7mG4/1).

Comment: The editText field in android should accept a decimal number with minimum integer part to be 1 and maximum to be 10. and the decimal part with minimum to be 0 and maximum to be 2.                                eg. Vaild
1 |   1.1 |     0.1
Invalid 
01     | 01.1     | 0.10

Comment: I need a regular expression for this which should work in Android. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Please try `^(?!0+[1-9])[0-9]{1,10}(?:\\.(?!0{1,2}$)[0-9]{1,2})?$`.